# create a "remove fields" button after new fields are dynamically added?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple form that adds an extra row of fields on the click of
   a green button.

1. I would like a 2nd red button to appear to the right of the green button
   after the the green button is clicked for the 1st time.
2. I would like this red button to remove the most recent row of fields
   added every time it is clicked
3. i would like for the red button to disappear when all added rows
   have been removed.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm not very experienced with javascript or jquery obviously.

The code is as follows:

**test.php**

```
<form role="form">
  <h3>
                            Band Details 
                            <small>Enter each band name and primary contact information...</small>
                        </h3>
  <div class="well" id="newBandRows">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for "newBandName">Band Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBandName" name="newBandName" placeholder="Enter Band Name" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="primaryContact">Primary Contact:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryContact" name="primaryContact" placeholder="Enter Name" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for "personEmail">Primary Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail" name="primaryEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for "personPhone">Primary Phone #:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" name="primaryPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone #" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="newRowButton">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" onClick="addNewBandRow();">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" align="right">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var band_i = 0;


function addNewBandRow() {
  band_i++;
  var bandDiv = document.createElement('div');
  bandDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class = "col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBandName' + band_i + '" name="newBandName' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Band Name"/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryContact' + band_i + '" name="primaryContact' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Name"/></div>    <div class="col-md-3"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail' + band_i + '" name="primaryEmail' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Email"/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone' + band_i + '" name="primaryPhone' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Phone #"/></div></div><br>';
  document.getElementById('newBandRows').appendChild(bandDiv);
}
```

Comment: A fun way to do that would be using AngularJs, a similar example is a todo list, you can see in [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: Are you really using jQuery, because it's not visible in your posted JavaScript - and isn't necessary for this feature to be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested Copy

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            var band_i = 0;
            var click = 0;

            function addNewBandRow() {
                click++;
                band_i++;
                var bandDiv = document.createElement('div');
                bandDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class = "col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBandName' + band_i + '" name="newBandName' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Band Name"/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryContact' + band_i + '" name="primaryContact' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Name"/></div>    <div class="col-md-3"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail' + band_i + '" name="primaryEmail' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Email"/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone' + band_i + '" name="primaryPhone' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Phone #"/></div></div><br>';
                document.getElementById('newBandRows').appendChild(bandDiv);
                if (click === 1) {
                    var rmDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    rmDiv.innerHTML = '<div id="remove">Remove</div>';
                    document.getElementById('remover').appendChild(rmDiv);
                }


            }
            function removeNewBandRow() {

                var container = document.getElementById("newBandRows")
                var children = container.childNodes;

                container.removeChild(children[children.length - 1]);
                //console.log(children.length);
                if (children.length === 3) {
                    var redbutton = document.getElementById("remover");
                    redbutton.parentNode.removeChild(redbutton);
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form role="form">
            <h3>
                Band Details 
                <small>Enter each band name and primary contact information...</small>
            </h3>
            <div class="well" id="newBandRows">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for "newBandName">Band Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBandName" name="newBandName" placeholder="Enter Band Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="primaryContact">Primary Contact:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryContact" name="primaryContact" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for "personEmail">Primary Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail" name="primaryEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for "personPhone">Primary Phone #:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" name="primaryPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone #" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="newRowButton">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-success pull-left" onClick="addNewBandRow();">+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="remover" onClick="removeNewBandRow();" ></div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" align="right">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, here are the steps you will need to implement:

1. Generate the HTML for the new red button.
2. This new red button will be hidden and unhidden based on a condition.

Example:

```
if (condition) {
  $('#secondRedButton').hide();
} else {
  $('#secondRedButton').show();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

3. Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event

Example:

```
$('#secondRedButton').click(function() {
  // do something
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well use simple hiding statements as this:

```
var band_i = 0;
function addNewBandRow(con){ 
  var e = con.getAttribute('name');
  var c = document.getElementById('delBtn');
  if(e == 'addRowBtn'){
    band_i++;
    var bandDiv = document.createElement('div');
    bandDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="row" id="' + band_i + '"><div class = "col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBandName' + band_i + '" name="newBandName' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Band Name"/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryContact' + band_i + '" name="primaryContact' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Name"/></div>    <div class="col-md-3"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail' + band_i + '" name="primaryEmail' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Email"/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone' + band_i + '" name="primaryPhone' + band_i + '" placeholder="Enter Phone #"/></div></div><br>';
    document.getElementById('newBandRows').appendChild(bandDiv);
    if(band_i != 0){
        c.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
function removeBandRow(con){
    var e = con.getAttribute('name');
    var c = document.getElementById('delBtn');
    if(e == 'delRowBtn'){
    var container = document.getElementById("newBandRows")
    var nodes = container.childNodes;
    container.removeChild(nodes[nodes.length - 1]);
    band_i--;
    if(band_i == 0)
        c.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

And modify buttons using this attributes.

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <button type="button" name="addRowBtn" class="btn btn-success pull-left" onClick="addNewBandRow(this);">+</button>
    <button type="button" name="delRowBtn" id="delBtn" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" onClick="removeBandRow(this);" style='display:none' >-</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for removing last child.

```
function removeBandRow(){
 var container = document.getElementById("newBandRows")
 var children = container.childNodes;
 container.removeChild(children[children.length - 1]);
}
```